# Use a custom template in sharepoint online for creating news page and it show the template owner as news page author

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, office-365

Creating a news post in SharePoint online using a custom template, the author of the newly created page is shown the Template author name, not by the creator of the news page?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the person field under the title of the page? That is just a common web part and you can update it with the user needed to be displayed.

The author of the news post will be correctly displayed in the Pages library per my test.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks.., Yes the author of the news post will be correctly displayed in the site Pages library but the news page can't change the author name automatically, it's still showing the template author name. Any way to change the name of the created by automatically

Comment: @Mariya, per my knowledge now. It is not a customizable web part. And you just need to edit it in seconds.